# How to remove empty space from a scatter plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have data that I am plotting similar to the example shown

```
#Data: Example data
x_data = [24.48,24.65,19.14,23.61,22.96,24.48,24.73]
y_data = [24.50,24.50,19.15,23.58,22.93,24.48,24.73]
plt.scatter(x_data, y_data, color = 'green', marker = '+', label = 'Example data')
plt.title('Example Data Plotted')
plt.xlabel('X_data')
plt.ylabel('Y_data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

As you can see the lowest number is 19.14. How do I get it to plot this data between somthing like 18 and 25 instead of what it does now where it starts from 0. I want to remove all the white space below the lowest number in this list.

Comment: The output of your code is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M3Xx.png), which does not start at 0. So it's unclear what you're asking. Please clarify.

Answer (score -1):

You should use :

```
plt.axes(xlim=(min(x_data),max(x_data)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
...
plt.xlim(18, 25) #adjust as you like
plt.ylim(18, 25) #adjust as you like
plt.show()
```

Check the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-shared-axis-demo-py)